# Deriving Complex class from TVector2 class: "No matching function for call to Complex::Complex()"

Tags: c++

I want to create a C++ class of complex numbers. Here is`Complex.h` (the most basic form)

```
#ifndef _COMPLEX
#define _COMPLEX

#include "TVector2.h"

class Complex : public TVector2{

 public:
 Complex(double re, double im): TVector2(re,im){;}

 protected:
  double m_re;
  double m_im;
};

#endif
```

Here is `main.cpp`

```
#include "Complex.h"
#include "TVector2.h"

int main() {

 Complex c;
}
```

This is the Makefile I am using

```make
CC         = g++ 
CFLAGS     = -g -Wall
CFLAGSROOT = `root-config --cflags`
LIBSROOT   = `root-config --glibs`

all: Main

Complex.o: Complex.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c Complex.cpp       $(CFLAGSROOT)


Main: main.cpp Complex.o
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o Main main.cpp Complex.cpp   $(CFLAGSROOT) $(LIBSROOT)

clean:
    rm *.o
```

I get this error:

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:9:11: error: no matching function for call to ‘Complex::Complex()’
   Complex c;
           ^
```

and these notes:

```
In file included from main.cpp:2:0:
Complex.h:16:2: note: candidate: Complex::Complex(double, double)
  Complex(double re, double im): TVector2(re,im), m_re(re), m_im(im){;}
  ^~~~~~~
Complex.h:16:2: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 0 provided
Complex.h:13:7: note: candidate: Complex::Complex(const Complex&)
 class Complex : public TVector2{
       ^~~~~~~
Complex.h:13:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
Complex.h:13:7: note: candidate: Complex::Complex(Complex&&)
Complex.h:13:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
Makefile:13: recipe for target 'Main' failed
make: *** [Main] Error 1
```

Comment: `Complex c;` Tries to invoke constructor without arguments (`Complex::Complex ()`), while the only constructor that `Complex` class has is `Complex::Complex (double, double)`. You can either provide the required constructor, or provide missing arguments.

Comment: In fact with Complex c(0,0); it compiles

Comment: Yes, because you provided the constructor arguments. That was one of my suggestions.

Comment: What if I want to write only Complex c?

Comment: I decided to write a proper answer, since there is no use for the answer to be in comments. But, it turns out, that I cannot do that, due to the fact that I don't know how `TVector2` is defined. Please provide [mcve]. I could, technically, write an answer regarding the constructor invocations, but, then you would run into the problem of `m_re`, and `m_im` not being initialized, and, to suggest the proper solution for that, I would need to have the definition of `TVector2`.

Comment: TVector2 is the class provided by CERN-ROOT https://root.cern.ch/doc/master/classTVector2.html

Comment: Is there a good reason you can't simply use `std::complex` for your task?

Comment: It's probably not a very good idea to publicly derive a class for complex numbers from a class of real 2-vectors. It is a *very bad* idea to derive it like that *and then add m_re and m_im data members*.

Comment: To tell the truth, TVector2 itself doesn't look like a very good idea. As anything from an all-encompassing single-rooted hierarchy really. C++ isn't Java.

Comment: @TobySpeight I have to create this class by deriving from TVector2 as an exercise.

Comment: If I were to grade such an exercise, I would give your answer a solid F because `m_re` and `m_im` data members. They are not supposed to be there.

Comment: @n.m. What should I do then?

Comment: Do you know *why* you were asked to derive complex from vector?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When writing `Complex c;` You are trying to invoke the constructor `Complex::Complex ()`, which is undefined in your `Complex` class, since the only available constructor takes 2 arguments `Complex::Complex (double, double)`.

So, there are couple of ways to solve such a problem:

1. Just provide the constructor arguments:

   ```
   Complex c (0, 0);
   ```
2. If providing constructor arguments looks too bulky, you can just provide a default constructor, that does the same for you:

   ```
   class Complex : public TVector2 {
   public:
       Complex (double re, double im): TVector2 (re, im) {}
       Complex (): TVector2 (0, 0) {}

   protected:
       double m_re;
       double m_im;
   };
   ```

   Or, if you are using at least C++-11:

   ```
   class Complex : public TVector2 {
   public:
       Complex (double re, double im): TVector2 (re, im) {}
       Complex (): Complex (0, 0) {}

   protected:
       double m_re;
       double m_im;
   };
   ```

   That would allow you write `Complex c;`.
3. If you wanted, however, to write `Complex c (5);`, which would 0-initialize `im` part, in addition to `Complex c;`, one can mark those constructor arguments as optional:

   ```
   class Complex : public TVector2 {
   public:
       Complex (double re = 0, double im = 0): TVector2 (re, im) {}

   protected:
       double m_re;
       double m_im;
   };
   ```

Note: I disagree with a notion of inheritance from `TVector2` to represent a complex number, since inheritance represents "is-a" relationship, and in my opinion complex number is not a vector (such vector contains several methods that doesn't make sense for a Complex number, and lacks several, which do). Even then, your `m_re`, and `m_im` members are not initialized, and contains indeterminate value, where using such a value would result in an undefined behavior.

Having that in mind, and changing, so it doesn't inherit from `TVector2`, the code snippets for would change to:

(2):

```
class Complex {
public:
    Complex (): m_re (0), m_im (0) {}
    Complex (double re, double im): m_re (re), m_im (im) {}

protected:
    double m_re;
    double m_im;
};
```

or (if you are using at least C++-11):

```
class Complex {
public:
    Complex (double re, double im): m_re (re), m_im (im) {}
    Complex (): Complex (0, 0) {}

protected:
    double m_re;
    double m_im;
};
```

(3) :

```
class Complex {
public:
    Complex (double re = 0, double im = 0): m_re (re), m_im (im) {}

protected:
    double m_re;
    double m_im;
};
```

Alternatively, unless, such code is for learning purposes, you can just use [`std::complex`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex).

Comment: Thank you. I thought about (2), but I have to do the derivation from TVector2 as an exercise.

Comment: @Lorenzo, Are you required to inherit *publicly*?  (If so, I hope it's only for didactic purposes, to show you what a bad idea that is!)

Comment: @Toby Sorry, why is that a problem?

Comment: It's a problem because a complex number is not a vector - if I'm doing vector geometry, it's surprising not to get an error if I mistakenly pass a complex number to a function that expects a vector.  Private inheritance won't allow that.